Selenium button click returns Error 500 and TimeoutException
I've been writing a copy and paste bot, it works well until it has to click the edit button:
Edytuj = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Edytuj pozycję']")))
Edytuj.click()

it ends with website error 500, and then it shuts down with TimeoutException.
Here is a piece of the HTML code:


<button _ngcontent-dspace-angular-c324="" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" title="Edytuj pozycję" aria-label="Edytuj pozycję"><i _ngcontent-dspace-angular-c324="" class="fa-fw fa-pencil-alt fas"></i></button>



I've tried locating the button with CSS selector and XPath, but there's always some error. I can't use the class name, because there is another button with the same class right next to it.
Edit: Adding a screenshot of a chunk of the code:
a screenshot of HTML code

did you try to actually click the button on that site, maybe it is located behind login or when you load the site it opens login page or something. or first try to trigger the click even in dev console through js to see if it works.

title="Edytuj pozycję"

I think this letter ę in the above HTML is the issue. It is changing to some other character when the HTML renders.
Assuming it returns only one element, try this XPath expression:
//button[contains(@title,'Edytuj')]

Or this:
//button[contains(@title,'Edytuj') and @class='btn btn-dark btn-sm']


A nice tip, but it doesn't solve the problem. The button is inside a flexbox, if it changes anything.

Can you share the URL of the site or share a little more of HTML around the button? Also, is the button inside an IFRAME, can you check?

The problem actually resulted from the page "reloading" again after loading once, causing the bot to not be able to click the button, because it reloaded mid-action. I added time.sleep instead of explicit wait and it works now. There probably is a better way of solving that though.
